# jQuery Loop JSON Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried a few combinations, but I am stuck. Any help is appreciated. How do I read the JSON record here please (is the syntax for the JSON organised well?) I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` with the code below and or permutations of it.

JSON:

```
{
  "wty_upgrade":[{
                    "wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 5 years", 
                    "mth":24, 
                    "pig":3000
                 }, 
                 {
                    "wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 10 years", 
                    "mth":84, 
                    "pig":8000
                 }]
}
```

CODE:

```
function LoadWtyUpgPlans(wty) {

    var WtyRow = '';
    var WtyYears = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < wty.wty_upgrade[0].length; i++) { 
        WtyYears = wty.wty_upgrade[0].mth[i] / 12;
        WtyRow +='<tr> \
                    <td> \
                        <input type="hidden" class="smg-wty-up-val" value="' + wty.wty_upgrade[0].mth[i] + '"> \
                        ' + wty.wty_upgrade[0].wty[i] + ' \
                    </td> \
                    <td align="right">' + WtyYears + '</td> \
                    <td align="right">' + wty.wty_upgrade[0].pig[i] + '</td> \
                </tr>';
    };
};
```

Comment: you don't need a loop if you're only using it for one element `wty.wty_upgrade[0].length`

Comment: where do you get your javascript object from?  How is it getting passed into the function?  do a `console.log(wty)` to see what's in there - where is it failing?  I'm going to assume it's `wty.wty_upgrade[0].mth[0]` here - try just `wty.wty_upgrade[0].mth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

The problem is you are not looping through the array, you are looping through the first index of the array. Second, you are trying to reference the index of the mth and pig. They are not arrays...

```
function LoadWtyUpgPlans(wty) {

    var WtyRow = '';
    var WtyYears = '';
    var upgrades = wty.wty_upgrade;

    for (var i = 0; i < upgrades.length; i++) {
        console.log("wty: ", upgrades[i].wty);
        console.log("mth: ", upgrades[i].mth);
        console.log("pig: ", upgrades[i].pig);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong at  wty.wty_upgrade**[0]**.length.  ==> wty.wty_upgrade.length

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider the way you iterate through your JSON. 
Let's say you define your JSON in a data variable like so:

```
var data = {"wty_upgrade":[{"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 5 years", "mth":24, "pig":3000}, {"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 10 years", "mth":84, "pig":8000}]}
```

Then you can use JQuery to iterate through your wty_upgrade array like this:

```
 $.each(data.wty_upgrade, function(){

         //EDIT:
         wtyYears = this.mth / 12; //this is the current array entry - first time: {"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 5 years", "mth":24, "pig":3000}


        WtyRow +='<tr> \
                    <td> \
                        <input type="hidden" class="smg-wty-up-val" value="' + this.mth + '"> \
                        ' +this.mth + ' \
                    </td> \
                    <td align="right">' + wtyYears + '</td> \
                    <td align="right">' + this.pig + '</td> \
                </tr>';
        $("#myTable").append(WtyRow); //you also need to append your row to a table or you'll never see it

    });
```

EDIT: added the missing division for second TD

http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/m0sc4dqz/2

And, as a best practice, you should not uppercase your variables - also make sure you include var whateverName = so you don't create a global variable!

Comment: @epascarello not sure what you mean - I considered this to be a place to solve problems? i made a suggestion on how to address the issue. my solution does not violate any best practices that I am aware of and was meant to be useful/helpful. i didn't mean to step on your toes ...

Comment: Second TD had logic, you are outputting a string from the JSON. AKA, it should be `WtyYears` which was `wty/12`