# JSON string assignment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What is wrong with my code below? I am passing to this function a JSON string but the assignment ends up blank. I can see the string in FireBug in the function parameter so I know it arrives at the function, but it does not make it past the assignment (as in the assignment is "undefined"). I want to pull from the string the `wty_upgrade` array. I am using some of the code I received help with [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917703/jquery-loop-json-issue). Thanks

JSON string (as I see it in FireBug:

```
{"wty_upgrade":[
    {"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 5 years", "mth":24, "pig":3000}, 
    {"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 10 years", "mth":84, "pig":8000}
]}
```

Function Call:

```
LoadWtyUpgPlans('3', JSON)

function LoadWtyUpgPlans(StdWty, UpgWty) {
    var WtyRow = '';
    var WtyUpgrades = UpgWty.wty_upgrade;    <--- here the assignment is blank/undefined
    STUFF HERE...
};
```

Comment: Is the first part meant to be JavaScript code, or....? If you're just quoting your JSON, remove the `JSON = "` at the beginning and the `"` at the end (e.g., as in the question you linked).

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder, you are correct it is not code. I get the value from a MySQL tabke field. Is the syntax of the JSON incorrect somehow?

Comment: @TheRealPapa can you show how you output the JSON to the page after you've retrieved it from the database?

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder, apologies again, I should have removed the `"`. I even checked the validity of JSON syntax here `http://jsonlint.com/ `and it is OK (without the outside `"`).

Comment: if I `alert(JSON)` it looks exactly as above. If I `alert(JSON.wty_upgrade)` it shows up `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can use as a this example may be useful fir you,
var jsn = '{"wty_upgrade":[
{"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 5 years", "mth":24, "pig":3000}, 
{"wty":"Upgrade from 3 to 10 years", "mth":84, "pig":8000}]}';


 //OR you can parse then use
jsonres = JSON.parse(jsn);
```

Comment: It seems to be working after JSON.parse now. I do not understand why it needs to, but it works. Thank you!